# Add 2 authentication shemes in blazor app

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, blazor

I am using a Blazor WebAssembly .NET 7, and I am trying to add a "Secure" authentication scheme to protect my Blazor page. However, I noticed that when I try to use the Authorize attribute with the argument @attribute [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = CustomAuthenticationSchemesNames.Secure)], it throws an error:

```
NotSupportedException: The authorization data specifies an authentication scheme with value 'Secure'. Authentication schemes cannot be specified for components. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.AuthorizeViewCore.EnsureNoAuthenticationSchemeSpecified(IAuthorizeData[] authorizeData).
```

So, I decided to use policies and created a "SecurePolicy", but it still does not work. After that, I created a cshtml component, and I do not know why, but it is working with razor pages.

Here some code:

Program.cs auth configuration:

```
 builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                })
                .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, opts =>
                {
                    opts.LoginPath = "/auth-group/select-group";
                    opts.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(240);
                })
                .AddCookie(CustomAuthenticationSchemesNames.Secure, opts =>
                {
                    opts.LoginPath = "/secure-auth/secure-login";
                    opts.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(240);
                });

            builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                var securePolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(CustomAuthenticationSchemesNames.Secure)
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();

                options.AddPolicy("SecurePolicy", securePolicy);
            });
...

  app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
```

My blazor test page component:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@page "/test-blazor-auth"
@inject NavigationManager navigationManager
@attribute [Authorize(Policy = "SecurePolicy")]

<h3>Test_Blazor</h3>

@code {
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
}
```

and test-cshtml component:

```
@page "/test-auth"

@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ProtectedBrowserStorage
@using SimpleSignon.Shared.Util
@model SimpleSignon.TenantWeb.Pages.Blazor.TestModel

<h1>Hello, Secure auth here</h1>

@{

}
```

and Page model of this test-cshtml component:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace SimpleSignon.TenantWeb.Pages.Blazor
{
    [Authorize(Policy = "SecurePolicy")]
    public class TestModel : PageModel
    {
        public void OnGet()
        {
            var res = HttpContext.User;
        }
    }
}
```

Here you can see how i sign my user:

```
var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme));

                            var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties()
                            {
                                RedirectUri = ReturnUrl,
                                IsPersistent = EnableLocalChromePassword,
                            };

                            if (FlowType == FlowTypeNames.Secure)
                            {
                                var securePrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CustomAuthenticationSchemesNames.Secure));

                                await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
                                    CustomAuthenticationSchemesNames.Secure,
                                    securePrincipal,
                                    authProperties);
                            }

                            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
                                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                                principal,
                                authProperties);
```

The flow of authorization should be as follows:

When the user is authenticated with the default Cookie Scheme, it should not allow the user to access the test-blazor component (but it currently does).

When the user is authenticated with the "Secure" scheme, they should be able to access the test-blazor component.

And of course, if the user is authenticated with both schemes, they should also be allowed to access the test-blazor component.

Do you have any ideas how can i fix my code to make authrization work for my blazor component?

Comment: Is [this question](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/47490#issuecomment-1489979100) related to your issue?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

It is some problem in the adding and checking policy. For the start try to config as

```
services.AddAuthorization(config =>
{
config.AddPolicy("IsAdmin", policy => policy.RequireRole("admin", "moderator", "superuser"));
});
```

and the attribute

```
Authorize(Policy = "IsAdmin")
```

In your code `.RequireAuthenticatedUser()` is only specified while configuration.